# How to activate some flag field when create a content?

Tags: flags

I have a many *flag* fields. When Authenticated users bookmark a content, they can enter value in flag fields.

I want to activate some fields of flag field when I create (add) a content.

For example, I have many flag fields of colors. When I create (add) a content, I want to activate some of the flag fields of colors. Because I want users to enter value of some colors, not all of color's field.

When I create first content I want to active 5 fields and when I create second content I want active 3 fiels and etc. I want to active some fields when I creating a content actually I want to have a control on flag fields.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hey @Hamed, I think you should put a little more work into your question. It's a bit hard to read. One easy improvement would be to try and break long sentences into smaller ones. And regarding the actual question: If I understand you correctly, you have many different color flags, e.g. Blue Flag, Red Flag, etc. And you want only some of these flags to be available to the users. Is this correct? Are these users anonymous? Do you want that all (anonymous) users have access to only a limited set of the Color Flags for all content? Or, is this set different for different content?

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>
> When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.
>
> You can, for example, define a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is checked.

Comment: dear @pierre  This module hasn't suitable for my goal.

Comment: Merci (oeps: thank you) for the feedback). Give me some time to think about a possible alternative ("sales start when the prospect says no", right?) ...

Answer (score 0):

Okey, this one was fairly easy.

You will need the [Flag per node](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_per_node) module.
Once you install this, you can select which flags are active for each node.
Below are some screenshots, demonstrating how different flags are available for different nodes. You can see each node's view and edit pages, on the bottom right corner of the node view pages you can see the active flag fields:

---

### Node A

[image]

[image]

---

### Node B

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's good, but doesn't manage flag fields, this module manages flag types. Thank you Stefanos.

Comment: Did you see the Screenshots? It manages flag fields, per node. ' I want to active some fields when I creating a content': it does exactly what you asked for. I don't understand your requirement,  or you didn't understand my answer. Have another look and correct me if I am wrong. Cheers

Comment: At the right side of a node, you can see the activated flag fields. See 1st and 3rd Screenshot.

Comment: Dear @stefanos I wrote an answer below. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I want to manage First Screenshot, not second Screenshot. First Screenshot is flag field, and second screenshot is flag type. 
[image: flag field]

[image: flag type]